# Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}) when render a map with InfoWindow

Tags: reactjs

I have the problem when render a map to show Window Info. But when running it, the error is "Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."
in InfoWindow (created by MapContainer)
in div (created by Map)

I searched and realized that I try to render an object in React. But when I check console.log(typeof this.state.selectedPlace.name), it give me string. I really don't know where the problem is and how to fix it.

```
export class MapContainer extends Component {
    state = {
        showingInfoWindow: false,  
        activeMarker: {},          
        selectedPlace: {}     
      };

      onMarkerClick = (props, marker, e) => {
        this.setState({
            selectedPlace: props,
            activeMarker: marker,
            showingInfoWindow: true
          });
      }

    onClose = props => {
      if (this.state.showingInfoWindow) {
        this.setState({
          showingInfoWindow: false,
          activeMarker: null
        });
      }
    };  


  render() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Map
                google={this.props.google} 
                zoom={14} 
                style={{width: '100%',height: 700}}
                initialCenter={{
                    lat: 16.081187,
                    lng: 108.211631
                }}>    
                <Marker 
                    onClick={this.onMarkerClick}                    
                    name={'Current location'} 
                />
                <InfoWindow
                    marker={this.state.activeMarker}
                    visible={this.state.showingInfoWindow}
                    onClose={this.onClose}
                >          
                    <div>
                        <h4>{this.state.selectedPlace.name}</h4>
                    </div>
                </InfoWindow>
            </Map>
        </React.Fragment>

    );
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem does not appear to be in in MapContainer. Have you taken a look at your InfoWindow component. You might be rendering an object using this.props.marker.

Comment: Deeply nested objects are often confusing because they seem to appear in the console but then give you this error in React when trying to render... The reason is `console.log` in the browser can be misleading... The data is not necessarily there until you expand the object... This is too complex to discuss in a comment... You need to structure and think about your state differently...